# Participle clause as sentence without conjugated verb?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax, present-participles, participle-clauses, periods

I've recently come across a sentence in an essay I proofread that went something like "Focusing on these experimental and statistical strategies." 
I thought it wasn't really a sentence and suggested sth. like "I will now focus on ...", "Now I focus on ..." or "We shall now focus on ...".

Now I've stumbled across this sentence starting a paragraph (it's not a heading or something like that) in a British textbook (Hogg & Vaughan, 2013: Social Psychology):

> Muzafer Sherif (1936) explicitly linking this convergence effect to the development of group norms.

Is this some participle use I've never heard of to introduce a topic or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a mistake to me. What did the previous sentence say? What you have could be citing a reference required by that previous sentence as in :" [something about convergence(Muzafer Sherif (1936) explicitly linking this convergence effect to the development of group norms).]

Comment: There's not really a direct previous sentence as it's the beginning of a new paragraph. The previous paragraph talks about the convergence effect mentioned.

Comment: Could it be a kind of sub-heading? They are sometimes formulated using the present participle? But it still looks like a mistake.

Comment: Subheadings like this are usually highlighted in some form in this book  (other color, italics); the sentence is in the running text. I think you're probably right and it is just a mistake similar to the other one I had seen before.